# How to run a Vagrant task on "vagrant destroy"?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm running Vagrant width Virtualbox, and I was wondering if there is a way to do a vagrant task when you destroy the machine (vagrant destroy)? Like when you run a task on provisioning ex:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|,
    s.inline: "echo Hello, World"
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Vagrant Triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers#example-usage) might help. Cleanup is apparently available in vagrant, but seems not to be implemented in the shell provisioner.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 5):

Just like You have in Your comments by Jon Stirling. 
[Vagrant triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers#example-usage) are the answer to Your a bit confusing question. Anyhow with triggers You can add a trigger .before and .after destroy happens.

For example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Your existing Vagrant configuration
  config.trigger.before :destroy do
    run "rm -Rf tmp/*"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was just looking for this to unregister a RHEL7 VM on RHSM before destroying it.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying to destroy a vagrant via command line : [See here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy.html)

The command `vagrant destroy` throws all data away.